# Role of Testers in Agile?

Tags: testing, project-management, agile, scrum

I work in a team which has been doing the traditional waterfall method of development for many years.  Recently, we've been told that future projects are going to be moving towards an agile (particularly Scrum) methodology.  It so happens that my project will be one of the first, so we will essentially be guinea pigs for the next few months to iron out what it takes to make the transition.

The project itself is in a very early stage and we would usually be many months away from releasing anything to the testing team, but now we are going to be working directly with them up front. As a result, I'm concerned as to the role of the testers in such a project at this stage.  I have several questions/concerns which hopefully some experienced agile developers could answer:

1. While a developer is coding a task, it is impossible for a tester to test it (it doesn't exist yet). What then is the role of a tester at this point
2. Is the tester now involved in unit testing? Is this done parallel to black box testing?
3. What does the tester do during a sprint where primarily infrastructural changes have been made, that may only be testable in unit testing?

How do the traditional test team members function in your agile project?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Testing-Practical-Guide-Testers/dp/0321534468

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more suitable for [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), it should be migrated to that site.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Keeping testers busy tends to get easier as a project matures (there is more to test!), but the following points apply in the early stages too:

1. Testers can prepare their test plans, test cases, and automated tests for the user stories before (or while) they are implemented. This helps the team discover any inconsistency or ambiguity in the user stories even before the developers write any code.
2. In my personal experience, testers don't have any involvement in unit testing; they only test code that passes all of the automated unit, integration and acceptance tests, which are all written by the developers. This split may be different elsewhere, though; for example your testers could be writing automated acceptance tests. Unit tests really should be written by the developers, however, as they are written in tandem with the code.
3. Their workload will vary between sprints, but regression tests still need to be run on these changes...

You may also find that having the testers spend the first couple of days of each sprint testing the tasks from the previous sprint may help, however I think it's better to get them to nail down the things that the developers are going to be working on by writing their test plans.

Answer (score 12):

Ideally QA and testers should be involved if not from the day one then from very early stages of a software development project, regardless of the process used (waterfall or agile). The test team will need to:

- Ensure that project or sprint requirements are clear, measurable and testable. In an ideal world each requirement will have a fit criterion written down at this stage. Determine what information needs to be automatically logged to troubleshoot any defects.
- Prepare a project specific test strategy and determine which QA steps are going to be required and at which project stages:  integration, stress, compatibility, penetration, conformance, usability, performance, beta testing etc. Determine acceptable defect thresholds and work out classification system for defect severity, specify guidelines for defect reporting.
- Specify, arrange and prepare test environment: test infrastructure and mock services as necessary; obtain, sanitise and prepare test data; write scripts to quickly refresh test environment when necessary; establish processes for defect tracking, communication and resolution; prepare for recruitment or recruit users for beta, usability or acceptance testing.
- Supply all the relevant information to form project schedule, work break down structure and resource plan.
- Write test scripts.
- Bring themselves up to speed with the problem domain, system AS-IS and proposed solution.

Usually this is not a question of whether a test team may provide any useful input into the project on an early stage, nor if such an input is beneficial. It is a question, however, of the extent to which an organisation can afford the aforementioned activities. There is always a trade off between available time, budget and resource versus the level of known quality of the end result.

Answer (score 8):

Good post. I was in the same situation about 3 years ago and the transition from waterfall to agile was tricky. I encountered many pain points in the move but once I overcame them and my role had changed I realised that this way of working really suits testing.

The common myth that testers are not required is easily dispelled.

**1. While a developer is coding a task, it is impossible for a tester to test it (it doesn't exist yet). What then is the role of a tester at this point**

In my experience the tester could be working with the customer to fine tune the stories in the sprint.

They are usually working with the developers to fine tune the code that they are delivering. i.e. advising on edge cases, flows, errors etc.

They can often be involved in designing the tests that the coder will write to perform TDD.

If the agile team is fairly advanced then the tester would normally be writing the ATDD (Acceptance Test Driven Development) tests. These could be in a tool such as Fitnesse or Robot Framework or they could be more advanced ruby tests or even some other programming language. Or in some cases, simple record and playback can often be beneficial for a small number of tests.

They would obviously be writing tests and planning some exploratory testing scenarios or ideas.

The tricky thing to comprehend sometimes for the team is that the story does not have to be complete in order to drop it to the test stack for testing. For example the coders could drop a screen with half of the fields planned on it. The tester could test this half whilst the other half is being coded and hence feedback in with early test results. Testing doesn't have to take place on "finished" stories.

**2. Is the tester now involved in unit testing? Is this done parallel to black box testing?**

Ideally the coders would be doing TDD. Writing the test and then writing the code to make the test pass. And if the coders are wanting really good TDD then they would be liasing with the tester to think up the tests.

If TDD is not being done then the coders should be writing unit tests at the same time as coding. It probably shouldn't be an after thought or after task after the software has been dropped. The whole point of tests is to test the software is correct to avoid wasting time later down the line. It's all about instant feedback.

**3. What does the tester do during a sprint where primarily infrastructural changes have been made, that may only be testable in unit testing?**

Ideally the tester would be working with the team and the customer (who by the way, is part of the team!) to define the planned stories and build in some good, detailed acceptance critiera. This is invaluable and can save loads of time later down the line. The tester could also be learning new automation techniques, planning test environments, helping to document the outcome of the planning.

Ideally each story in the sprint would be testable in some way, shape or form. This doesn't mean it should be by the test team, but should be testable. So the tester could be working with the rest of the team working out how to make sure stories are testable.

I post some agile tips here : http://thesocialtester.posterous.com/

Hope this helps you out
Rob..

Answer (score 3):

Just a few thoughts, definitely incomplete:

1. While the developer is coding a task, the tester can be examining the specifications (or requests from the customer, if there are no formal specs) and writing the test plan. This can include a conceptual framework for what needs to be tested, but it should also include formally writing test suites (yes, in code) as well.  This can be quite a challenge for teams moving to agile, as a lot of testers are hired without programming skills. (In a lot of places, it seems like it's a *requirement* to not be able to code.)
2. The tester can be involved in unit testing, or in a slightly higher scope by testing components or libraries that have a clean interface.
3. The testers should *always* be executing regression tests, load tests, and any other kinds of tests that he can think of, as well as writing test suites for the next sprint.  It's often the case that testers work one sprint ahead of development (in preparing a test environment), as well as one sprint behind development (in testing what developers just produced).

Answer (score 3):

I saw a good [talk](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/agile-testing/how-we-build-quality-software-at-uswitch-com) on this recently. Basically this team started off doing a fairly standard Scrum process, then transitioned to Kanban and Lean. One of the most important things they did was to gradually erode the distinctions between testers and developers. Testers were involved in writing unit tests and code, developers were bringing in more higher level tests early in development. It was a steep learning curve for the testers, but worth it as the team was building in quality from the start. By now the testers call themselves developers because their work is so integrated in the process of writing code.

Answer (score 2):

At my company we use and endorse Agile. Our QA team members are involved in unit test creation, maintaining the regression testing infrastructure and, just like in waterfall, they also test each feature upon completion.

When doing infrastructural changes, they also participate to make sure that the new infrastructure is testable.

So, from my limited experience, I'll try to answer your points:

1. If there's nothing to test yet, start setting up a regression/testing infrastructure and make sure that whatever is being done will be testable
2. Yes, he may do both
3. Maintains the testing infrastructure and hunts whoever breaks the tests

Answer (score 2):

> 1) While a developer is coding a task, it is impossible for a tester to test
>   it (it doesn't exist yet). What then
>   is the role of a tester at this point

The tester may still create test plans and have a list of what tests will be created.  There may also be the need for the tester to get training if the development involves some off-the-shelf software,e.g. if you are doing a CMS project with Sitecore then the tester should know a few things about Sitecore.  There can also be some collaboration of the tester, the developer and the end user or BA to know what are the requirements and expectations so that there isn't the finger pointing that can pop up in vague requirements.

> 2) Is the tester now involved in unit testing? Is this done parallel to
>   black box testing?

Not in our case.  The tester is doing more integration/user acceptance testing rather than the low-level unit testing.  In our case, unit tests come before any QA tests as the developers creating the functionality will create a layer of tests.

> 3) What does the tester do during a sprint where primarily infrastructural
>   changes have been made, that may only
>   be testable in unit testing?

Regression testing!  In making infrastructural changes, did anything break?  How thorough a testing suite can developers run compared to QA?  We had this in a sprint not that long ago where most of the sprint work was plumbing rework so there wasn't much to test other than seeing that things that worked before still work afterward.

In our case, we have testing as one level up from our development environment but still a pre-production environment.  The idea is to allow QA a sprint to validate the work done and for any critical or high severity bugs to be found and fixed before a release into staging for final user acceptance testing, so if developers are working on sprint X then QA is validating sprint X-1 and production may have sprint X-2 or earlier running depending on the final UAT and deployment schedule as not every sprint will make it into production after QA gives the OK to move into staging.  There are pairing exercises that can happen once a developer is done an initial coding of a task to ensure that both a tester and an end user sign off on what was built.  This is our third or fourth version of trying to integrate quality control into the project so it is still a work in progress that has evolved a few times over already.

Comment: Your answer would be easier to read if you repeated the questions asked.

Answer (score 2):

The most natural approach to testing in an agile environment is in my opinion exploratory testing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_testing.
Doesn't sound words like

> According to Cem Kaner & James Bach, exploratory testing is more a [mindset] or "...a way of thinking about testing" than a methodology

or

> pair testing

sound familiar to agile developpers. Testers can be involved much earlier in the process than in traditional testing.

Answer (score 1):

Like a few other respondents have indicated, Testers should be involved from day one. In Sprint zero they should be involved in ensuring that the Stories the Product Owner is producing are testable (e.g. verifiable once coded) and "acceptable" (i.e. when you go though UAT). Once the Product Backlog is initially populated then the Testers can work on test cases for the Stories slated for the current Sprint, and once there is a product for them to test (Ideally somewhere in your first Sprint) then they can start testing.

If it sounds like there will never be anything to test for a few Sprints, you've got your stories wrong. The aim of a Sprint, even an early one, is to have a thin slice of the eventual system. Focus on "asprin" (i.e. if building a drug prescription system, how do you deliver testable functionality in 2-4 weeks? Build the ones for prescribing an asprin) and "tracer bullets" stories (ones which, when taken in combination touch all the risky parts of the architecture). You'll be amazed what you can hand over to test early on.  If testers do end up with spare time, get them to pair program with the developers. It'll build relationships and mutual respect.

The benfits of this approach are many but primarily you test out a good deal of the internal people-processes of your development (handovers from requirements, to development, to test, and also the reverse) and secondarily the whole team (all three disciplines mentioned) sees the benefits of rapid feedback as a result of producing executable software.

It sounds impossible, but I've seen it work.  Just make sure you don't bite off too big a chunk to begin with.  Let yourselves ease into it and you'll be amazed.